# Laravel timestamp saving time as unix timestamp

Tags: laravel

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to change in laravel to save timestamps in database as unix valid timestamp?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use carbon https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please read about Laravel date mutators:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

> By default, timestamps are formatted as 'Y-m-d H:i:s'. If you need to
>   customize the timestamp format, set the $dateFormat property on your
>   model. This property determines how date attributes are stored in the
>   database, as well as their format when the model is serialized to an
>   array or JSON

Also, you can override `getDateFormat()`:

```
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'U';
}
```

And use this in your migration files:

```
$table->integer('updated_at');
$table->integer('created_at');
```

And, if you use soft deletes:

```
$table->integer('deleted_at');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, what would the property look like to be able to save timestamps as valid unix timestamps?  I found this in documentation: protected $dateFormat = 'U';   but couldn't find what would the format be like for Unix timestamps?

Comment: Just use this in your model and Laravel will use UNix time format, like: 1414706400

Comment: But when I use this, in my database for every timestamp field I get 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Try to use `->table` elements from my post in your migration. It uses `timestamp()` by default.

Comment: everything worked now, when I did as you said! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. )

Comment: make getFormatDate() public in Laravel 7