# Force Eloquent Models to output all timestamps as long

Tags: laravel, eloquent, timestamp

I'm working on a backend using Eloquent Models. In order to set a default way to output dates, I'm looking for a way to tell the Eloquent Model to output its date attributes as a long (unix-timestamp).

```
$user = User:find(id);
echo $user->toJson();
```

// the current output

```
{
   "id":1,
   "username":"root",
   "created_at":"2016-12-25 18:23:34",
   "updated_at":"2016-12-25 18:23:34"
}
```

// the desired output

```
{
   "id":1,
   "username":"root",
   "created_at":1482690214,
   "updated_at":1482690214
}
```

Is there a clean way to override the outputing toJson() or any other way to achieve this?

**Edit**

Do you thing that it's a good idea to override the magic __get()? Or does Eloquent use another way to access the attribute when calling toJson?

Answer (score 1):

Set desired format [to `$dateFormat` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915610/1227923):

```
protected $dateFormat = 'U';
```

> By default, timestamps are formatted as `Y-m-d H:i:s`. If you need to customize the timestamp format, set the `$dateFormat` property on your model. This property determines how date attributes are stored in the database, as well as their format when the model is serialized to an array or JSON

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: InvalidArgumentException: Trailing data in ...\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php on line 425

Comment: I got this exception when trying your solution sir. What have I done wrong?

Comment: @KarimKharba try to change migration to use `integer` instead of using `timestamps` like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915576/laravel-timestamp-saving-time-as-unix-timestamp/35915610#35915610).

Comment: This would mean to change the db schema (which something I want to avoid). Is there a way to override the outputing function to Json? or to use a mutator?

Comment: You could try to manually create [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) for `created_at` and/or `updated_at`

Comment: Please, can you provide a small snippet to demonstrate how to achieve that? This would be very helpful sir.

Comment: I've added two links to my previous comment, you can see examples of accessor and mutator there. Try to use Carbon's `$value->format('U')` to transform date to Unix timestamp (accessor) and `Carbon::parse($date)` to create Carbon instance from Unix timestamp (mutator).