# Carbon 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Trailing data' when overriding $dateFormat attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

In order to force my Eloquent Models to output dates in unix-timestamp (not string formatted) when serialized with toJson() method, I have overridden the $dateFormat attribute as the following:

```
$dateFormat = 'U;
```

This seems to be the recommended way to change how Date attributes are outputted. (Please [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323970/force-eloquent-models-to-output-all-timestamps-as-long)).
But I'm getting the following errors by doing so.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with
>   message 'Trailing data' in
>   ...\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php on line 425

Followed by this one:

> InvalidArgumentException: Trailing data in ...\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php on line 425

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well you did not close your string literal for one thing.