# Laravel/Lumen cast timestamp to int

Tags: php, laravel, casting, lumen

The timestamps are created using `$table->timestamp('createdAt');`
To get the unix timestamp value. I've casted it in Model as:

```
protected $casts = [
    'createdAt' => 'datetime:U',
]
```

However, `$model->toArray();` gets the unix timestamp as string instead of int/number.

```
"createdAt"=> "1537003313",
```

It should be:

```
"createdAt"=> 1537003313,
```

I'm using toArray method to avoid iterating the rows. So `(int)$model->createdAt;` isn't an option.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915576/laravel-timestamp-saving-time-as-unix-timestamp . hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with int casting

```
(int)$timestamp
```

In your case it should be

```
$casts['createdAt'] = (int)$casts['createdAt'];
```

Read this for more Information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: The question is more towards how it can be done at laravel's end using Model or something.  I cannot use explicit type casting.